# Not able to create project in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to create project in ionic using CLI. I've installed ionic and cordova using **npm install -g ionic cordova** but when i tried to create project using **ionic start appname tabs** , this is doing nothing. Am i lacking somewhere?

Here is console output

```
 D:\komal\angular5\ionic>ionic start --list
            tabs ............... ionic-angular A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
            blank .............. ionic-angular A blank starter project
            sidemenu ........... ionic-angular A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
            super .............. ionic-angular A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
            conference ......... ionic-angular A project that demonstrates a realworld application
            tutorial ........... ionic-angular A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
            aws ................ ionic-angular AWS Mobile Hub Starter
            tabs ............... ionic1 A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
            blank .............. ionic1 A blank starter project for Ionic
            sidemenu ........... ionic1 A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
            maps ............... ionic1 An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu

            D:\komal\angular5\ionic>ionic start ionic-tabs-app tabs

            D:\komal\angular5\ionic>ionic start ionic-tabs-app sidemenu

            D:\komal\angular5\ionic>ionic start myApp tabs

            D:\komal\angular5\ionic>ionic -v

            3.20.0

         C:\>cd ionic

        C:\ionic>ionic start myApp tabs

        D:\komal\angular5\ionic>cordova -v
      ? May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool 
      over time? Yes

     Thanks for opting into telemetry to help us improve cordova.
     8.0.0
     D:\komal\angular5\ionic>node -v
     v6.11.1
```

Comment: please add console output as text not image. Also can you show the output of ionic -v ?

Comment: Sure.  You can check this now.

Comment: can you run `ionic -v` in the cmd?

Comment: the version is 3.20.0

Comment: hmm.. nothing wrong with the installation. Just a hunch.. can you try starting a project in your user folder in C drive?

Comment: still same thing is happening

Comment: does cordova -v work?

Comment: Yeah the version is 8.0.0

Comment: that is weird.. could be permissions thing.. try with admin cmd or raise an issue in github

Comment: i already tried it by running as admin

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: The node version is 6.11.1

Comment: Strange - with same versions, its working for me. Try upgrading NPM and Node as an option

Comment: Both are of latest versions